# Python: Explicit declaration of attributes' staticness

Tags: python, python-3.x

I come from a C++ and Java enviroment and just started learning Python, hence this question. From [The Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/#id3) there's a quote:

> Explicit is better than implicit.

So, is there a way to explicitly declare a static and/or non-static attributes in Python all at once?

For example (**not fully a python code**):

```
class BasicClass():
    # Explicit declaration of a attribute shared through the class and instances
    x = 0

    # Explicit declaration of a attribute that I would like to be owned only by the class
    static:
        y = 10

    # Explicit declaration of a attribute that I would like to be owned by every instance individually
    non_static:
        z = 0

    def __init__(self, x, z):
        self.x = x
        self.z = z

a = BasicClass(1, 2)
b = BasicClass(3, 4)
```

Although this 'static' and 'non_static' keywords don't exist in Python, this is the behavior that I would want to achieve:

1. The `x` attribute should be accessible through `BasicClass.x` as well as `a.x` and `b.x`. Being all distinct instances.
2. The `y` attribute, since it's "static", should be owned by (and accessed through) the `BasicClass` instance only.

   - It would be ok if `a.y` worked as a reference to `BasicClass.y`, for example.
3. The `z` attribute, since it's "non-static", should be accessible through `a.z` and `b.z`, being both distinct instances, and must not be acessible directly through `BasicClass` since it must not have this attribute.

I think the first desired behavior is what is really going on.

Regarding the seccond one, it's clear why a attribute like `y` is important and desired.

And about the tird one, I know that it's possible to declare an attribute as such along the methods of the class. But can it be declare **all at once**? And if not, why? Again if not, is it better this way?

Explicitly declaring all inside the `__init__(self, ...):` function can be a problem since I can want an attribute to don't be initialized. Or is this a bias from C++/Java?

Comment: Python''s model differs materially, there is no equivalent of 'static' in C++. **Everything** in the class body definition is 'static'.

Comment: Maybe you are actually looking for [`dataclasses`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html)

Answer (score 1):

Python has no concept of 'static' attributes, not in the way that C++ defines them.

Instead, Python attribute lookup on an instnace goes through the following steps; if a step succeeds then that determines the outcome and further steps are skipped:

1. Check for a [data descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) on the class (including the full MRO hierarchy). These get priority over an instance attribute. The descriptor is bound and the result of binding is returned. E.g. a [`property` object](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html).
2. If the instance has its own `__dict__` namespace, check for the attribute there
3. Check for the attribute on the class hierarchy (step 1 will have cached this if it wasn't a data descriptor). If it is a descriptor, bind it, e.g. a function is bound to produce a method at this stage.
4. If the class hierarchy has a `__getattr__` method defined it is called to see if it can provide a result.

That's it; instances and classes are, at its most basic, a layered namespace. Attributes are not declared, they exist because they are simply *used*.

You *can* use [type hinting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) to help tools like IDEs and static type validators check for type correctness, and you can use such hints to declare that your class will use specific instance attributes with a given type, e.g.:

```
from typing import ClassVar

class BasicClass:
    x: int = 0            # instance and class attribute, with a default value for the class
    y: ClassVar[int] = 10 # explicitly a class attribute
    z: int                # instance attribute

    def __init__(self, x: int, z: int) -> None:
        self.x = x
        self.z = z
```

but the Python runtime will not *enforce* any rules about what attributes can be set where. A static type checker like [mypy](http://mypy-lang.org/) will, however, raise an error when you run it on code that sets `y` on an instance of `BasicClass`:

```
$ tail -n 2 thdemo.py  # two lines added to the above example
a = BasicClass(42, 81)
a.y = 117
$ mypy thdemo.py
thdemo.py:14: error: Cannot assign to class variable "y" via instance
```

If you are not using type hinting, then you never have to 'declare' attributes. Attributes just 'are', you use them or you don't. Python assumes we are all grown-ups that can write unit tests where deemed necessary, and is otherwise almost entirely dynamic. This gives you a great deal of flexibility and power to do things that are much harder and much more verbose in C++ or Java.

Answer (score 0):

Python is simple, it doesn’t require a static keyword.

Variables assigned in the class declaration are class variables or static variables, while those inside the class methods are instance variables.

```
class Employee:
   empName = 'Vicky' #class variable

   def __init__(self, age, id):
        self.age = age                #instance variable
        self.id = id                  #instance variable

one = Employee(21, 1)
two = Employee(30, 2)

print(one.empName) # prints "Vicky"
print(one.age) # prints 21
```